# Images showing up in Post Editor, but not in Published Post

Tags: posts, images, themes

I am trying to add three images by just inserting them into the post here: http://www.ihts.nl/wie-wij-zijn/

Although I can see the images perfectly in my Media Library as well as in the post editor itself, somehow they don't show inside the actual post (only their captions).

I have never encountered this issue before, would someone please be so kind to assist me?

Comment: what are the image names?

Comment: For instance, this is the image that should show up above 'Theo Poort': http://www.ihts.nl/wp-content/uploads/politie.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is there.  If you view the source you can see it.  If you inspect the image in your browser you can see its hidden with CSS and set to display:none;

This is the style your theme is applying.

```
.single .entry-content img {
    display: none;
}
```

You will need to override that style with your own.

```
.single .entry-content img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That's it!

Thank you so very much, I'm not so great with CSS and hadn't seen this. I really appreciate your help!